# How to add a page break from pandoc markown to RTF output?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, rtf

I tried to add `\page` and `\page\par\` to the markdown to trigger a page break in the resulting RTF file but that does not work. Adding `\newpage` works with a LaTex output. Is there something similar for RTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw RTF commands have to be marked as such, as pandoc will otherwise interpret it as a raw TeX command and throw it away.

This should do:

````
```{=rtf}
\page
```
````